# How to connect druid ( standalone Not cluster ) to superset and explore data on the dashboard?

Tags: druid, apache-superset

I have superset up and running and I also have a druid service and Kafka broker running. I want to know how to connect druid to superset so I can explore and query the data that I have in druid. I feel like you can only connect a druid cluster, not a standalone or I am just not understanding all the configurations when I try to add a druid cluster on the superset UI such as broker host and port. Any Idea?

Comment: A very well documented tutorial on ingesting the data to Druid via kafka.. https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-kafka.html For visualizing data to superset, you need to first configure the druid cluster in superset and follow above steps to ingest data to druid... The datasource will be visible in superset only after you have ingested some data...

Comment: how to configure it in superset that is where I got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Follow following steps:

Step 1: On Superset web ui, go to Sources -> Druid Clusters, add a new druid cluster and druid coordinator and broker information.

Step 2: Ingest the data to druid, following steps at druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-kafka.html

Step 3: After ingesting the data ( both supervisor spec and data ingestion to druid using Kafka), Go to Sources -> Refresh Druid Metadata, you will find the data source you are trying to add. Select that data source for visualization.

Comment: The " Druid Clusters" menu isn't even visible for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

i was really struggling with this one... in my case, i am running on my mac. druid is installed directly and superset is running in docker (using the docker-compose setup).

the key is that localhost in the superset docker container doesn't point at the host, but instead at the docker container.

when i changed the superset datasource to this, it worked...

[druid://host.docker.internal:8082/druid/v2/sql/](http://druid://host.docker.internal:8082/druid/v2/sql/)